# Is Autovacuum global setting applied to all tables?

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

I have autovacuum globally enabled, sql query:

```
select * from pg_settings where category like 'Autovacuum'
```

shows that autovacuum setting is "on".

Does that mean all tables in the database will be subjected to autovacuum periodically, or I need to additionally set autovacuum to "on" individually for every table in order to autovacuum it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that means it's globally enabled.

You don't need to turn on manually for each table.